# Distill failed for unknown reason -- unable to get image dimensions ... of first.imageset/first.pdf

Tags: xcode, pdf, compiler-errors, assets

This past Friday afternoon I was running Xcode and my app.  Then at some point that afternoon Xcode crashed.  I restarted it but it now won't compile. I get a "Distill failed for unknown reason".  When I look at the log of this error I see Xcode is trying to get the dimensions of two files: Assets.xcassets/first.imageset/first.pdf and Assets.xcassets/second.imageset/second.pdf but failing.  No wonder -- those files are there but have zero-bytes.

I don't understand because I have run Xcode and this app 20 to 50 times a week for the past year (more or less).  When I look at back-ups of the project (as far back as Feb 4, 2020) these two PDF files have always been zero-bytes.

I am running Xcode 12.1 on Catalina 10.15.7.  I have seen similar questions posted and tried the posted solutions (Build-Phase/CopyBundleResource/remove-clean-reAdd/rebuild) but that does not help.  Can anyone shed light on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

My bad.  One set of my back-ups (made by coping the project folder) had zero length PDF files (???) but the TimeMachine set of back-ups had good files.  When I copied in the good files Xcode now compiles the project.

Why coping the project folder as a back-up didn't work is still a mystery to me.